# Getting post id from RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to have it so when the user taps on a post from the `RecyclerView` I can get the post id I am following [CodinginFlows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WR4QAiVuCw) video on how to do it but when I get to `getSnapshot()` I don't have the option to use it

I looked at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult#getSnapshot()) and it says that the interface has been deprecated I am not sure if this is referring to all of it or just something specific.

I am using Cloud Firestore am I going about this the right way or am I way off?

> snippet

```
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {

       super(itemView);
       mView = itemView;
       parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Main_Blog_Post);

       itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Posts").document(id);
                String postID = docRef.toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,postID,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listner != null){

                    listner.onItemClick(get);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

> Full code if needed

```
public class BlogRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private OnItemClickListner listner;

public List<BlogPost> blog_list;

private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

private Context mContext;

public BlogRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<BlogPost> blog_list) {
    mContext = context;
    this.blog_list = blog_list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item, parent, false);
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    CollectionReference mUsersDB = db.collection("Posts");


    String desc_data = blog_list.get(position).getDesc();
    holder.setDescText(desc_data);

    String image_url = blog_list.get(position).getImage_url();
    holder.setBlogImage(image_url);

    long millisecond = blog_list.get(position).getTimestamp().getTime();
    String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(millisecond)).toString();
    holder.setTime(dateString);

    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Confirmation_Activity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return blog_list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public Context mContext;
    ConstraintLayout parentLayout;
    private View mView;
    private TextView descView;
    private ImageView blogPostView;
    private TextView blogDate;
    private TextView blogUserName;
    private CircleImageView blogUserImage;
    private StorageReference mImageStorage;
    private DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Main_Blog_Post);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Posts").document(id);
                String postID = docRef.toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,postID,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listner != null){

                    listner.onItemClick(get);
                }

            }
        });

    }


    public void setDescText(String descText) {
        descView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_desc);
        descView.setText(descText);

    }

    public void setUserData(String downloadUrl, String name) {

        mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);
        mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String name = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).toString();

                StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_uid + (".jpeg"));
                Log.d("heere", "S");

                // This gets the download url async
                filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        //The download url
                        final String downloadUrl =
                                uri.toString();
                        Log.d("tag", downloadUrl);
                        if (!downloadUrl.equals("default")) {

                            //  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(downloadUrl).into(mDisplayImage);
                            Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(downloadUrl).into(blogUserImage);

                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.d("value", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                Log.d("key", dataSnapshot.getKey());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    public void setTime(String date) {

        blogDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_date);
        blogDate.setText(date);

    }

    public void setBlogImage(final String downloadUri) {

        blogPostView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);
        Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(downloadUri).into(blogPostView);


    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListner{
    void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);

}

public void setOnItemClickListner(OnItemClickListner listner){
    this.listner = listner;

}
}
```

[image: db]

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve DocumentReference  id?

Comment: I am trying to get the id of the document as it is stored in firebase check image attached

Answer (score 0):

While not very familiar with the deprecated `getSnapshot()` method, you can get the document reference id by adding it as a field when you initially add the post to the database.

e.g.

```
 DocumentReference documentReference =  firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").document();//generate the random blog_id here
    Map<String, Object> postMap = new HashMap<>(); //hashmap do add files to your db
    postMap.put("image_url", image);
    postMap.put("desc", companyName);
    postMap.put("blog_id", documentReference.getId());
    //add the rest of the document here
    documentReference.set(postMap).addOnCompleteListener....
```

`documentReference.getId()` will get your blog id as a string and you will be adding it to the database with the key blog_id

Then you will need to update your BlogPost model class to have a blog_id variable too same as you already have or description and image url.

Then inside your recycler adapter inside onBindViewHolder

```
String blog_id = blog_list.get(position).getBlog_id();
```

Now you have blog_id on the string and you can pass it anywhere you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I just want to make sure this will work with my problem. My current situation is when the user creates a post it adds the post document to its respected collection then adds a new document to a different collection with the SAME id as the post this new document allows the users to send messages to each other. so my plan is when the user taps on the post it gets the id of the POST and then i pass that to a variable and then use that to retrieve the id of the Messages document if its confusing let me know

Comment: It's not confusing. If i understand correctly you want two documents to have the same name essentially. In this case ids. PostID and MessageID under the same name(id). This is what you're looking for then.
Create the post first > name with the autogenerated post id.
Create the message > name it with the post id that was generated earlier. Correct?

Comment: yes I already have the two documents being created so that is done I just can't figure out how to get the id when the user taps on the post because there are multiple posts by different users I can't just store the variable when the post is initially created

Comment: why can't you store the variable when the post is initially created? I just gave you the example that does that exact thing AND makes it easier to tell which post did the user click.

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood your post i thought i wouldn't be able to store the initial post id as a variable because if user A creates a post and then has that id store in a var when user B comes and selects the post they won't have it stored. because they didn't create the post

Comment: `DocumentReference documentReference =  firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").document();`//generates the random id `documentReference.getId()` Gets the id as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that `getSnapshot()` method is deprecated because it isn't, `Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult` interface is. In order to be able to get the id of the document you are looking for, your adapter class should extend `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` class. So in that case, to get the id of the document you can certainly use the `getSnapshots()` method like in the following lines of code:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull YourModelClass yourModelClass) {
    String id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
}
```